# How can I edit spatial data automatically on postgis and check for topology errors on said data whitout using shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, postgis, open-source-gis, topology, validation

So, I have spatial data stored in postgis (points, lines and polygons) and would like to edit and update those in an Open Source software (quantum GIS, grass, etc.) to check for topologic errors, among others stuff, (arc-node-polygon topology) in an automatic way. So when I edit or update this data it would automatically be saved in the geodatabase whithout using the
import from DB -> edit -> create shapefile -> import shapefile to DB routine.
I know the ArcSDE can do all of this, but I need it done with Open Source software alone. Is there a way to do it?

Ps: It would be best if those editions and updates would respect my database relationships between tables, but if not, the problem can be solved using triggers on postgis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: About reading data and saving data in QGIS -> Layers -> Add PostGIS layer (why use shapefiles at this point), Edit layer, save changes. There is  Topology Checker tool in vector tools (not sure if it is plugin or included in base install). 

So you can have following workflow. Open PostGIS table, edit , check topology, fix errors, save postgis layer. I don't know any ready to use solutions to do it at automatically at insert/update phase in plain postgis db
 
There is also http://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html and https://github.com/strk/qgis_pgis_topoedit (i have not tested those)